# SQL Join 2 Case from a third table

Tags: sql-server

### **Background**

I have three tables:

1. MetaMachine (MM)
2. MetaShift (MS)
3. MachineData (MD)

**MM** Contains all relavent static data about a specific machine, including what worker shift is operating it.

**MS** Contains the different shifts, sub shifts, StartTime(hh:mm) and Duration(h) of said shifts

**MD** Contains sensor readings from the machines, all DateTime Stamped (DTS).

### **Problem**

I want to know what happened during ghost hours, i.e. when machine was running without any operators.

The logic I wish to apply is: (Please note this is my made up SQL)

```
Select 
 MD.*
,MM.Shift 
    CASE
        WHEN Time(MD.[DTS]) > MS.[ShiftStartTime] & < (MS.[ShiftStartTime]+MS.[ShiftDuration]) THEN ‘In Shift’
        ELSE ‘Ghost’
    END AS IN_OUT_SHIFT
FROM MetaShift as MS, MachineData as MD
JOIN MetaMachine as MM on MD.MachineNR = MM.MachineNR
```

The idea is that I can join MD and MM so that I have added the shift name as a column in MD, I know need to check in the MS table if the recorded timestamp is in any sub shift that day.

Please note that a machine can have 1 to 3 different sub shifts depending on day and shift type.

Another issue I am experiencing is over night shifts i.e. shifts that start ca 22:00 and end 06:00 the day after.

### Exampale tables

```
MetaMachine    
|   MachineNr |       Shift      | Manufacturer |
--------------------------------------------------
|   1         |    2shift        |  Siemens     |
|   2         |    4shift        |  ABB         |
|   3         |    4shift        |  IKEA        |
|   4         |    TurkyShift    |  ABB         |


MachineData
|             Tstamp            |   MachineNr |   Sensor1 |   Sensor2 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|    2019-05-11 01:00:00.000    |   1         |    10     |     -35   |
|    2019-05-11 01:30:00.000    |   2         |    10.1   |      19   |
|    2019-05-11 01:30:05.000    |   4         |    0.98   |     100   |
|    2019-05-12 01:00:00.000    |   1         |    3.7    |     58    |

MetaShift
|Shift  |Shift Name |WeekDay    |   ShiftStart  |Duration (h)   |Duration (s)   |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|2shift |V1     |Monday     |05:54:00       |7,90       |28440  |
|2shift |V1     |Tuesday    |05:54:00       |7,90       |28440  |
|2shift |V1     |Wednesday  |05:54:00       |7,90       |28440  |
|2shift |V1     |Thursday   |05:54:00       |7,90       |28440  |
|2shift |V1     |Friday     |05:54:00       |7,90       |28440  |
|2shift |V1     |Saturday   |               |0      |   |
|2shift |V1     |Sunday     |               |0      |   |
|2shift |V2     |Monday     |14:00:00       |9,40       |33840  |
|2shift |V2     |Tuesday    |14:00:00       |9,40       |33840  |
|2shift |V2     |Wednesday  |14:00:00       |9,40       |33840  |
|2shift |V2     |Thursday   |14:00:00       |8,40       |30240  |
|2shift |V2     |Friday     |           |0      |   |
|2shift |V2     |Saturday   |           |0      |   |
|2shift |V2     |Sunday     |           |0      |   |
|4shift |V1     |Monday     |06:00:00       |8,00       |28800  |
|4shift |V1     |Tuesday    |06:00:00       |8,00       |28800  |
|4shift |V1     |Wednesday  |06:00:00       |8,00       |28800  |
|4shift |V1     |Thursday   |06:00:00       |8,00       |28800  |
|4shift |V1     |Friday     |06:00:00       |6,00       |21600  |
|4shift |V1     |Saturday   |06:00:00       |12,00      |43200  |
|4shift |V1     |Sunday     |06:00:00       |12,00      |43200  |
|4shift |V2     |Monday     |           |0      |   |
```

Comment: It seems a bit to hard to follow without any table structures, plus a bit of data, then some expected results.  If you could make some simplified tables, with maybe just enough data to lead to one example result.  People have provided this in the past by posting a script to generate populated Table Variables, for example

Comment: although I realise that you may currently be trying to design tables

Comment: Iunderstand its hard to follow, I will try and figure out a way to represent the tables in a simple way. :)

Comment: if possible then please share your table structure with some dummy data

Comment: I have added some dummy tables with the same structure, please note that each machine writes 5 rows worth of data per second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it but it is probably not the most efficient way. :) 
Please if you have any feedback to increase efficiency I am all ears.

```
select
    MD.Timestamp,
    case when ShiftString is null then 'Ghost' else Shift end GhostOrNoGhost 
    , *
from (
    SELECT 
        M.ShiftName
        ,(  
            select top 1 MS.ShiftName + ' ' + MS.ShiftSubName + ' ' + MS.ShiftDay + ' ' + convert(nvarchar(20),MS.ShiftStart) + case when Counts > 1 then ' xxx ' + convert(nvarchar(4), Counts) else '' end
            from (
                select MS.ShiftName, MS.ShiftSubName, MS.ShiftDay, MS.ShiftStart,
                    count(*) over () as Counts
                from MetaShift as MS
                where MS.ShiftName = MM.ShiftName
                and datename(dw,dateadd(second,-MS.ShiftDuration*3600,MD.Timestamp)) = MS.ShiftDay
                and convert(time, MD.Timestamp) >= MS.ShiftStart and MD.Timestamp < convert(datetime, convert(date,MD.Timestamp)) + dateadd(second,+MS.ShiftDuration*3600,convert(datetime,MS.ShiftStart)) 
            ) x
        ) ShiftString
        ,MD.*

    FROM [MachineData] as MD
    JOIN [MetaMachine] as MM on MM.MachineNr = MD.MachineNr
) x 
order by MD.Timestamp
```